# Access content for Anonymous and logedIn User

Tags: python, django

How best can I access content while the user is not logged in. For example, I have the View which handles both Listing and posting blog posts , though I want someone to access content even without being logged In, though the person shouldn't create a blog post, unless logged In.

Below is my current implementation :

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """Blog post lists"""
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context=request)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return response.Response(serializer.data,
                                     status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, )
        return response.Response(serializer.errors,
                                 status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So how best can I play with these lines :

```
authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

**EDIT :**

because when I remove this line :

```
authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
```

I can't access the lists of blogs, I get this response :

```
{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}
```

though I will need an endpoint of creating a blog posts to be protected, how best can this be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom permission by inheriting the `permissions.BasePermission` class and override the `has_permission` method according to your requirements.

```
class PostsProtectOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method not in permissions.SAFE_METHODS\
            and not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return False
        return True
```

The `permissions.SAFE_METHODS` is a tuple containing `GET`, `HEAD` & `OPTIONS` methods which are basically read-only methods. So if a user requests to create a new  entry then the method used will be `POST` method which is not considered as safe method. And to check if the user is loggedIn or not use `request.user.is_authenticated`.

And now use the custom permission for you api view.

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """Blog post lists"""
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (PostsProtectOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, but will this cover the fact that if I dont have this line `authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)` it will work ? because when I remove it it show me this response :

```{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}```

Comment: Yes, You can use the permission with `authentication_classes`. It will work.

Comment: Am now getting :
`rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: 'CustomPermission' object has no attribute 'authenticate`

Comment: can you share the updated code and error in you question?

Comment: I have updated my question, thanks

Comment: You cannot use the permission in authentication. make them separate

Comment: If I also do something like this :

```authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
     permission_classes = [PostsProtectOrReadOnly]```
same error

Comment: I've updated the answer. please check again.